# help on an arithmetic exercise

Tags: number-theory, systems-of-equations, arithmetic

> Let $p$ a prime number of the form $p = 4k + 1$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $a \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $a^2 + 1$ is a multiple of $p$.
>
> We denote $r$ the integer part of the number $\sqrt{p}$ and $E$ the set $\{0, 1, \dots, r\}$.

Show that there are two distinct pairs $(x, y)$ and $(x', y')$ of $E^2$ for which the
two natural integers $x + ay$ and $x'+ ay'$ have the same remainder of the Euclidean division on $p$.

Comment: Please try to include information in your post about your approach and where you hit a wall.

Comment: I don't have any idea that's why I asked, can you give me some idea. Thank you for your time.

Comment: it would be better if you mention that you are not sure about how to approach the question in the post, otherwise the post may be downvoted.

Comment: sure, I just want to tell you that I'm a young boy and i English wasn't my first language, this question wasn't a test or something for school, it's just for love. thank you for your time.

Comment: please do not take this as a personal attack, it's just a piece of advice. Try showing your working (even if it is one line long) in the post so that anyone that is trying to help get an idea of where you went wrong.

Comment: LOOOL, don't worry. I respect you for your advice and I will never take it as a personal attack. thank you another time. by the way, if you have an idea share it or give the way to answer it myself LOOOL .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x,y)=x+ay;0\le x,y\le r$. There are $(r+1)^2$ distinct ordered pairs $(x,y)$. But $r=\lfloor\sqrt p\rfloor<\sqrt p<\lfloor\sqrt p\rfloor+1=r+1$. Thus, $(r+1)^2>p$, which means we have more ordered pairs than numbers in the canonical residue system of $p$. Thus, when we see $f(x,y)\mod p$, there must be at least two distinct pairs $(x,y),(x',y')$ such that $f(x,y)\equiv f(x',y')\mod p$.

Comment: thank you for your time, can you explained more the 3rd line  please .

Comment: We have $(r+1)^2$ integral values of $f(x,y)$ each of which must be congruent to exactly one of $p$ integers in the canonical residue system $\mod p$, for example, $\{0,1,2,...,p-1\}$. Since $(r+1)^2>p$, at least two distinct pairs $(x,y),(x',y')$ give the same value $\mod p$.

Comment: it's helpful. thank you very much